# Predicate functor inheriting from unary_function, that isn't a function taking 1 argument

Tags: c++, stl, predicate, functor

I have a functor class inheriting from unary_function:

```
template<class T>
class Matcher : public std::unary_function<T, bool>
{
private:
    int m_match;

public:
    Matcher(int valToMatch) : m_match(valToMatch) { };
    bool operator() (T toTest)
    {
        return T.prop == m_match;
    }
}
```

A function which is using one of these things:

```
void DoStuff(std::unary_function<ThisType, bool> & pred, 
             vector<ThisType> & stuffToTest)
{
    for(vector<ThisType>::iterator it = stuffToTest.begin();
        it != stuffToTest.end(); ++it)
    {
        if(pred(*it))      // <<< Compiler complains here
        {
             // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

The original calling function:

```
Matcher myMatcher<ThisType>(n);
// have vector<ThisType> myStuff
DoStuff(myMatcher, myStuff);
```

As far as I know, I have a templated functor, of which I am constructing an instance with the ThisType type, which I pass to the function expecting a unary_function argument and call with an instance of ThisType.

But the compiler complains that "term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because even though you're passing the derived class object to the function, the function parameter is still `std::unary_function` which doesn't have member `operator()` taking one argument. Hence the error.

I would suggest you to change your function  to a function template as:

```
template<typename F>
void DoStuff(F && pred, vector<ThisType> & stuffToTest)
{
    for(auto it = stuffToTest.begin(); it != stuffToTest.end(); ++it)
    {
        if(pred(*it))  
        {
             // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very clear. Only problem with templating DoStuff here is that it is already specific to ThisType, so the predicate will always be pred(ThisType).

Comment: @PhilH: That shouldn't matter. If you want, you could use `std::function<bool(ThisType)>` as parameter type, but I wouldn't suggest that, as it hinders optimization, and will produce slower-code due to type-erasure, on the other hand template code will produce faster code, as it might inline the functor.

Comment: I'll have to rethink, then, as this is in a pre-0x (but with tr1) version of C++.

Comment: @PhilH: Oh then template is the only option; also use `F` instead of `F&&` as parameter.

Answer (score 2):

[unary_function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/unary_function) is not a polymorphic type, it's just a base class which is there to provide the `argument_type` and `result_type` member types.

You can pass to your `DoStuff` function a `std::function<bool(ThisType)>` or you make you `DoStuff` function template

Comment: Cheers, unfortunately I only don't have access to C++11 with this compiler.